# Is there any smart compact rower?

Tags: exercise-equipment, home-exercise, rowing-machine, websites

Is there any **compact** rower that can sync with MyFitnessPal? so one could keep track of rowing distance and calories burnt everyday?
[image]

Comment: 'Compact' implies you have size/location restrictions.  Is that correct?  You make no mention of your budget.

Comment: Correct @rrirower. I don't have budget constraints. I just want it to be <4ft in length and capable of syncing distance and calories burnt data with Myfitnesspal. And I'd prefer it be a full motion rower.

Comment: If budget is not a constraint, I would recommend you take a look at the leader in rowing machines: [Concept2](https://www.concept2.com/).  I own an older model that breaks down into two pieces that fit within 3 feet of space.  More importantly, the performance monitor on the machine allows you to track several metrics in a "log book".

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @rrirower. However, it isn't compact enough for a small room, smart enough to cloud-sync with MyFitnessPal or full motion.

Comment: Not sure you noticed the connection at the footplate that allows for disconnecting the machine into two pieces and storing it vertically.  That's how I store it.  Additionally, what by you mean by "full motion"?  The concept2 rower provides the most accurate rowing motion.

Comment: That disconnection is for long term storage or transportation, not for daily deployment in a 10'x10' office room, @rrirower. 
[Full motion rowing](https://www.fitnessgizmos.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/31/Sunny-Health-Fitness-Incline-Slide-Rower.gif)

Comment: As an on-water and machine rower, I can tell you that what you posted in your comment is not a natural rowing movement.  It's more of a hack squat movement.  If you'd like to discuss this further, I am available to discuss it in private messages.